# Access PHP object array

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

Need some quick advice I am trying to access a object array but I am struggling, please see the below array. It starts off an object I would normally user $result->_messages->token but it doesnt work I have trawled google and this site but cant access the token.

```
object(Zend_Auth_Result)#76 (3) {
["_code":protected] => int(1)
["_identity":protected] => string(9) "3232323233"
["_messages":protected] => array(2) {
    ["user"] => object(stdClass)#71 (13) {
      ["id"] => string(9) "232323332"
      ["name"] => string(14) "John Smith"
      ["first_name"] => string(5) "John"
      ["last_name"] => string(8) "Smith"
      ["link"] => string(41) "http://www.facebook.com/"
      ["username"] => string(17) "john.smith"
      ["location"] => object(stdClass)#68 (2) {
        ["id"] => string(0) ""
        ["name"] => NULL
      }     
      ["email"] => string(22) "john@doe.com"
      ["timezone"] => int(1)
      ["locale"] => string(5) "en_US"
      ["verified"] => bool(true)
      ["updated_time"] => string(24) "2012-06-21T13:57:12+0000" 
    }
    ["token"] => string(109) "AAAGIFdDivU4BAMoxyHT3bqY8eBGhnWo9YKM1szHZAnWgY10AIBgxz9LeNCeA2HV9Yhkp8uM5Aq0WR39ZBdcnOa4MxXVI22rnmFKNbYdQZDZD"
    }
}
```

Any advice any body?

Cheers

J

Comment: That's not an array, it's an object of type `Zend_Auth_Result`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ZF Reference Guide on Naming Conventions:](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html#coding-standard.naming-conventions.variables)

> For instance variables that are declared with the "private" or "protected" modifier, the first character of the variable name must be a single underscore. This is the only acceptable application of an underscore in a variable name. Member variables declared "public" should never start with an underscore.

So you cannot access `_messages` directly from outside the `Zend_Auth_Result` instance, because it is [`protected`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). You have to use the getter for that property.

See the API Docs for [`Zend_Auth_Result`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Auth/Zend_Auth_Result.html)

```
$messages = $zendAuthResult->getMessages();
$token = $messages['token'];
```

Comment: Managed to figure your solution out by looking at how the controller get the User info.  Worked perfect thanks!

Answer (score 3):

_messages is protected so it's impossible to call upon that variable from outside this (or extended) class, check whether a method exists for the class to get the variable in the array

Comment: Thanks, bit of a problem then!  The Facebook.php file returns the array with the code :  return new Zend_Auth_Result( Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS, $user->id, array('user'=>$user, 'token'=>$params['access_token']) );